# Having trouble pushing an app to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm in the process of pushing a webapp I designed in Rails to Heroku, but I'm having trouble when pushing the app to heroku. According to the console, when it starts preparing the app for the Rails asset pipeline, the rake aborts. At the end I get this error:

> ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
>   error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/connectr-demo.git'

I have heard that this is because of conflicts in the commits, but I have already pulled from github and everything is up to date, or at least the console is reporting so. At the recommendation of a similar question, I tried using "git fetch origin" and "git pull --rebase" but got the exact same results. I still get this error when I try to push to heroku. Can anyone tell me how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Is it a fast-forward merge, or do you need to force push?

Try `git push -f heroku master`...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running `heroku run rake db:migrate` and then try re-pushing to heroku `git push heroku master`

Comment: Yes, I have tried that. It yielded the same results.

Answer (score 0):

The `(pre-receive hook declined)` means that Heroku didn't recognize the app. Make sure that the rails app is in the root directory of the repo not in a sub directory, make sure you have a Gemfile and make sure that it is named correctly.

Comment: I do have a Gemfile. I'm not sure how to check the root directory of the repo and I'm not sure what you mean by the correct name. Could you elaborate?